# Do rsync --checksum and diff usually have different outputs or is my hdd broken?

Tags: rsync, diff, corruption, checksum, data

I set up a NanoPi Neo 2 with OpenMediaVault (Debian Jessie) as its OS and have an hdd attached to it (the OS is on an SD card).
When I now copy my data from my external hard drive onto my system with `rsync -avP --checksum [source] [dest]` and check back if everything went well with `diff -r [source] [dest]`, it still tells me that some files differ.
That happens even after repeating the procedure several times and even if I delete the differing files according to diff and resyncing everything.

So my question is: is this a normal behaviour and nothing to worry about or is my (new) hard drive on the system somehow faulty and therefore the new files get corrupted quickly after (hopefully correct) transfer with rsync?

Comment: It might be cool to see if you could get a minimal example that reproduces this issue. Pick one of the files where `diff` and `rsync` disagree and then try rsyncing just that one file to make sure you still get conflicting results. Then start shrinking that file until the conflict disappears (e.g. using `head -c` to grab the first n bytes. Alternatively, start small and work your way up until the problem occurs.

Comment: To make that clear: After every rerun, diff tells me that other files are different than the last time...

Comment: So there are files that appear to be different on one run (according to `diff`) and then appear to be the same on the next run?

Comment: @igal: yes, exactly. but on the next run other files are claimed to be different....

oh, and btw: I have some photos for example and when I copy them back to my laptop, they open perfectly and I cannot see any problems with the files that are apparently different

Comment: Have you tried rsyncing a single file (repeatedly)?

Comment: I have not (yet), but I've just tested diffing the two directories twice right away and comparing the outputs and - strangely enough - I get different results when doing nothing in between....
maybe this has to do with the fact that I'm syncing from a hfs+-filesystem to ext4? I am lost, but I just think I'll go along and hope my sync has done everything right. thank you so far.